# React Js .json() leaves out some data that are available from the api

Tags: php, reactjs, postman

I am working on a project that gets an array of integers from the api and prints them on the screen. The problem here is, POSTMAN shows that there is data in json format with no errors as shown in the figure but react js says there's no data.

[The api code, the sizes in $attributes are there just to see that react takes those but doesn't take others that come form the database (Click To See the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq4Wp.jpg)
This is the api code.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->load->database();
    }

    public function getAllProducts()
    {
            $query = $this->db->get('products');
            return $query->result_array();
    }

    private function cutifyProduct($productResult,$isSingle=false){
            foreach($productResult as $key => $product){
                    $productId = $product['id'];
                    $mediaQuery = $this->db->get_where('media',array('productId'=>$productId));
                    $categoryQuery = $this->db->get_where('categories',array('id'=>$product['categoryId']));

                    $thisProductCategory = $categoryQuery->result_array()[0];
                    $productResult[$key]['categoryTitle'] =  $thisProductCategory['name'];

                    if($isSingle){
                            //for breadcrumb
                            $breadcrumb = [];

                            $breadcrumb[] = $thisProductCategory;
                            while($thisProductCategory['parentId']!=0){     

                                    $categoryQuery = $this->db->get_where('categories',array('id'=>$thisProductCategory['parentId']));
                                    $thisProductCategory = $categoryQuery->result_array()[0];
                                    $breadcrumb[] = $thisProductCategory;
                            };

                            $productResult[$key]['breadcrumb'] = $breadcrumb;

                            //for product attributes

                            $attributes = [];

                            $tempSizeAttribute = array();
                            $tempColorAttribute = [];
                            $tempStorageAttribute = [];
                            $tempRamAttribute = [];
                            $attributesQuery = $this->db->get_where('attributes',array('productId'=>$productId));
                            $thisProductAttributes = $attributesQuery->result_array();

                            $attributes['size'] = array(
                                    "sizeType"=>"UK",
                                    "sizes"=>array(1,2,3),
                            );
                           foreach($thisProductAttributes as $productAttribute){
                                    if($productAttribute['title']=="size"){        
                                            //$attributes['size']['sizes'][] = (int) $productAttribute['name'];
                                            $tempSizeAttribute[]=(int) $productAttribute['name'];
                                    }elseif($productAttribute['title']=="color"){
                                            $tempColorAttribute[] = array(
                                                    "productId"=>explode("|",$productAttribute['name'])[0],
                                                    "name"=>explode("|",$productAttribute['name'])[1],
                                            );
                                    }
                            }
                            $attributes['size']['sizes'] =array_merge($attributes['size']['sizes'],$tempSizeAttribute);
                            $productResult[$key]['attributes'] = $attributes;


                            //for vendor information
                            $vendorInfo = [];
                            $vendorQuery = $this->db->get_where('vendors',array('id'=>$product['vendorId']));
                            $vendorResult = $vendorQuery->result_array();
                            $productResult[$key]['vendorDetails'] = $vendorResult;



                    }
                    $productResult[$key]['media'] =  $mediaQuery->result_array();
                    $productResult[$key]['link'] = "/product/".$productResult[$key]['slug'];
                    if($productResult[$key]['discountPercent']=="0.00" || $productResult[$key]['discountPercent']==0 || $productResult[$key]['discountPercent']=="0" || $productResult[$key]['discountPercent']=="0.0"){
                            $productResult[$key]['price'] =  array(
                                    "current"=> $productResult[$key]['price'],
                            );    
                    }else{
                            $productResult[$key]['price'] =  array(
                                    "current"=> $productResult[$key]['price'] - (($productResult[$key]['discountPercent']*$productResult[$key]['price'])/100),
                                    "previous"=> $productResult[$key]['price'],
                            );
                    }
                    foreach($productResult[$key]['media'] as $mediaKey => $media){
                            if($isSingle){
                                    if($media['isPrimary']=="1" || $media['isPrimary']==1  ){
                                            if(substr( $media['url'], 0, 4 ) != "http"){
                                                    $productResult[$key]['image']= "https://admin.ratomatoshop.com/media/medium/".$media['url'];
                                            }
                                    }

                                            if(substr( $media['url'], 0, 4 ) != "http"){
                                                    $productResult[$key]['images']['medium'][]= "https://admin.ratomatoshop.com/media/medium/".$media['url'];
                                                    $productResult[$key]['images']['original'][]= "https://admin.ratomatoshop.com/media/original/".$media['url'];
                                            }else{
                                                    $productResult[$key]['images']['original'][]=$media['url'];         
                                            }

                            }else{
                                    if($media['isPrimary']=="1" || $media['isPrimary']==1  ){
                                            if(substr( $media['url'], 0, 4 ) != "http"){
                                                    $productResult[$key]['image']= "https://admin.ratomatoshop.com/media/small/".$media['url'];
                                            }
                                    }
                            }


                    }
            }
            return $productResult;
    }

    public function getLatestProducts($noOfProducts)
    {
            $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
            $this->db->limit($noOfProducts);
            $query = $this->db->get('products');
            $productResult =  $query->result_array();
            return $this->cutifyProduct($productResult);
    }

    public function getOnSaleProducts($noOfProducts)
    {
            $this->db->order_by('discountPercent', 'DESC');
            $this->db->limit($noOfProducts);
            $query = $this->db->get('products');
            $productResult =  $query->result_array();
            return $this->cutifyProduct($productResult);
    }

    public function getTopRatedProducts($noOfProducts)
    {
            $this->db->order_by('rating', 'DESC');
            $this->db->limit($noOfProducts);
            $query = $this->db->get('products');
            $productResult =  $query->result_array();
            return $this->cutifyProduct($productResult);
    }


    public function getProductData($productSlug)
    {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('products',array('slug'=>$productSlug));
            $productResult =  $query->result_array();
            return $this->cutifyProduct($productResult,true);
    }

    public function getFeaturedProducts($noOfProducts)
    {
            $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
            $this->db->limit($noOfProducts);
            $query = $this->db->get('featuredproducts');
            $results = $query->result_array();
            $products = [];
            foreach($results as $result ){
                    $products[] = $this->getWhere('id',$result['productId']);                
            }
            return $this->cutifyProduct($products);
    }

    public function getSpecialProducts($noOfProducts)
    {
            $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
            $this->db->limit($noOfProducts);
            $query = $this->db->get('specialproducts');
            $results = $query->result_array();


            $products = [];
            foreach($results as $result ){
                    $product = $this->getWhere('id',$result['productId'])[0];
                    $product['dateEnd'] = $result['dateEnd'];
                    $product['discountPercent'] = $result['discountPercent'];
                    $products[] = $product;
            }

            return $this->cutifyProduct($products);
    }

    public function newProduct($productData)
    {
            return $this->db->insert('products',$productData);
    }

    public function isProduct($productId){
            $product  = $this->getWhere('id',$productId);
            if($product!=null && is_array($product) && count($product)>0){
                    return true;
            }else{
                    return false;
            }
    }

    public function getWhere($key,$value){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('products',array($key=>$value));
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

}

[The postman response from the api (Click To See the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua0tG.jpg)
This is the post man response

```
"attributes": {
    "size": {
        "sizeType": "UK",
        "sizes": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            36,
            37,
            38,
            39,
            40
        ]
    }
},
```

[The json data that react gets. (Click To See the code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1w1R.jpg)

This is the react's console log:

```
"attributes": {
    "size": {
        "sizeType": "UK",
        "sizes": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: It is basically impossible that `.json()` leaves out data in any form. If the server response is valid json, it will be in the object. Open your react application in e.g. chrome, open the inspector, got to the network tab and look at the request to the api. You should be able to see the json serialized response there. If it doesn't contain your data the server did not send it.

Comment: hey @trixn i have updated the question. Please re check

Comment: @trixn it's the same in the network tab too. the data is incomplete there too

Comment: Then the problem is clearly on the server side. If the response contains the data you would see it there.

Comment: @trixn but since the postman shows that the there's data, what could be the problem. It there was problem in the server side, postman should also have not shown the data there.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more details. Are you sure you are comparing the server sent response and the client received response of the same request? Data does not get lost like this. Maybe the product you are fetching does not have the expected attributes and `$tempSizeAttribute` is empty.

Comment: Can you share your full api code and the request with choosen method? (GET)

Comment: If it is working in postman, but the network tab shows different results, then ensure you are sending the same headers with both the postman request and the request you make in react.

Comment: How do you view the result in Postman? (Raw, Pretty,...)

Comment: @trixn I checked everything, there's data in the $tempSizeAttribute, and the server is the valid json format,

Comment: @Michael I have updated the full api Code in the question. The method I used in react and post man is POST method. I view the result in Preety + JSON. I have checked the response(from postman) and verified it to be a valid JSON.

Comment: @TPHughes how do I check the headers ? I haven't checked but I am preety sure that the headers are the same.

Comment: I dont know which browser do you use, but go to dev tools and network tab. There you can check header and also the raw response. I think there is something happening in the transition from the API json response >> react output. @trixn already mentioned

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/

Comment: nothing helped though

Comment: Is this API public? If yes, you can share the API call

Comment: I don't see any reason why Postman would give a different response to the react app. As long as all of your headers, data and such are the same. You can find the headers sent by react by hitting the network tab and looking at the request. Post that whole slab of data as well as a screenshot or something of your postman app so we can see. Something has to be different between the two I would think.

Comment: Can you be absolutely certain that what you have posted is the exact response? Is that the data you are receiving before you process it in any way? Log the raw response from the api.

Comment: @Michael  the api url is : https://api.ratomatoshop.com/index.php/Products/getProductData/black_snickers_for_women.

Comment: This is the result I get from your API: "sizes": [36, 37, 38, 39, 40]. You get them from DB I guess. How do the values in DB look like? Its super strange...